# I am having problem with accessing an array from other class

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

In this code, I am storing the content read from a file into an array. I have successfully done that but when I try to read from another class or just display it or so it just throws a null pointer exception.

Basically, I tried to write the array into a file so I could have one reading and the other writing the content that the previous class read. But my code couldn't even display the array so how would I be able to write to a file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reading extends Thread{
    String location;
    List<String> temps;
    public static String[] tempsArray;
public Reading(){
    
}
    public Reading(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
    
        String store ;
     
          try
          {
           
            try (Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File(location)).useDelimiter(",\\s*")) {
                temps = new ArrayList<>();
                // while loop
                while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
                    // find next line
                    store = inFile1.next();
                    temps.add(store);
                }       }

  tempsArray  = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (String s : tempsArray) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
          }
          catch(IOException e){
              System.out.println(e);
              
          }
       
          System.out.println("File Reading Sucessful");
    }
 
 
}
class Writing extends Thread{
    Reading red = new Reading();
    String location;
    public Writing(String location){
        this.location = location;
    }
```

here I tried to make code display the array that had stored the content

```
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Reading r = new Reading();
       try{
          for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
              System.out.println(r.temps.get(i));
          }
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
       }
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reading r = new Reading("Input.txt");
        Writing w = new Writing("Input.txt");
        r.start();
        w.start();
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make object => `Reading r = new Reading();` in `run()` of `Writing` class this object doesn't hold the reference of the same class object `Reading r = new Reading(input.txt);` in main method.
That is why Writing class's Reading object doesn't hold the values that actually hold by Reading object of main class.